# Get cumulative mean among groups in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get a cumulative mean in python among different groups.
I have data as follows:

```
id  date        value
1   2019-01-01  2
1   2019-01-02  8
1   2019-01-04  3
1   2019-01-08  4
1   2019-01-10  12
1   2019-01-13  6
2   2019-01-01  4
2   2019-01-03  2
2   2019-01-04  3
2   2019-01-06  6
2   2019-01-11  1
```

The output I'm trying to get something like this:

```
id  date        value   cumulative_avg
1   2019-01-01  2   NaN
1   2019-01-02  8   2
1   2019-01-04  3   5
1   2019-01-08  4   4.33
1   2019-01-10  12  4.25
1   2019-01-13  6   5.8
2   2019-01-01  4   NaN
2   2019-01-03  2   4
2   2019-01-04  3   3
2   2019-01-06  6   3
2   2019-01-11  1   3.75
```

I need the cumulative average to restart with each new id.
I can get a variation of what I'm looking for with a single, for example if the data set only had the data where id = 1 then I could use:

```
df['cumulative_avg'] = df['value'].expanding.mean().shift(1)
```

I try to add a group by into it but I get an error:

```
df['cumulative_avg'] = df.groupby('id')['value'].expanding().mean().shift(1)

TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

Also tried:

```
df.set_index(['account']
ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

The actual data I have has millions of rows, and thousands of unique ids'. Any help with a speedy/efficient way to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For many groups this will perform better because it ditches the `apply`. Take the `cumsum` divided by the `cumcount`, subtracting off the value to get the analog of `expanding`. Fortunately pandas interprets 0/0 as `NaN`.

```
gp = df.groupby('id')['value']
df['cum_avg'] = (gp.cumsum() - df['value'])/gp.cumcount()

    id        date  value   cum_avg
0    1  2019-01-01      2       NaN
1    1  2019-01-02      8  2.000000
2    1  2019-01-04      3  5.000000
3    1  2019-01-08      4  4.333333
4    1  2019-01-10     12  4.250000
5    1  2019-01-13      6  5.800000
6    2  2019-01-01      4       NaN
7    2  2019-01-03      2  4.000000
8    2  2019-01-04      3  3.000000
9    2  2019-01-06      6  3.000000
10   2  2019-01-11      1  3.750000
```

Comment: @Ben.T, No typically it's not that bad, and often a `groupby.apply` is necessary for more complicated aggregations, or even seeming simple aggregations that chain together basic methods within a group. But it does turn out to be a slow python-level loop over the groups. And so if you find yourself in a situation where you have 5M groups with maybe 5-10 observations per group it's nearly as slow as a typical `DataFrame.apply`

Comment: The major speed-up here comes from the fact that `cumsum` and `cumcount`, as built-in `GroupBy` aggregations, go to much faster `cython` branches for the calculation.  Obviously all aggregations can't be boiled down to simpler math like this, but when it can it could be worth the trade-off. Your solution is far more straight-forward and self-documenting, so I'd go with that in most scenarios where there's no real gain in something taking 3ms compared to 300ms.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @ALollz: it's outstanding :) +1

Answer (score 5):

After a `groupby`, you can't really chain method and in your example, the `shift` is not made per group anymore so you would not get the expected result. And there is a problem with index alignment after anyway so you can't create a column like this. So you can do:

```
df['cumulative_avg'] = df.groupby('id')['value'].apply(lambda x: x.expanding().mean().shift(1))
print (df)
    id        date  value  cumulative_avg
0    1  2019-01-01      2             NaN
1    1  2019-01-02      8        2.000000
2    1  2019-01-04      3        5.000000
3    1  2019-01-08      4        4.333333
4    1  2019-01-10     12        4.250000
5    1  2019-01-13      6        5.800000
6    2  2019-01-01      4             NaN
7    2  2019-01-03      2        4.000000
8    2  2019-01-04      3        3.000000
9    2  2019-01-06      6        3.000000
10   2  2019-01-11      1        3.750000
```